# passing var-args to MessageFormat.format in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to parse errorCode like

```
4011=Error thrown expected: {0} found: {1}.
```

using Message.format in kotlin

```
loggingService.logTheMsg("4011", arrayOf("${expectedVal}", "${actualVal}"))
```

In logTheMsg I am using this code :

```
var errorMessage = props.getProperty(errorCode)
errorMessage = MessageFormat.format(errorMessage as String, args)
println("${errorMessage}.")
```

but getting output as :

```
Error thrown expected:[Ljava.lang.String;@38f3b4ba found: {1}.
```

It might help in answering , the same thing is achieved in java like this:

```
parse(value, new String[]{"firstName","lastName"});
```

And in parse:

```
parse(String value, String[]args) {         
    value = MessageFormat.format((String) value, args);         
    System.out.println(value); 
}
```

prints:
my name is firstName lastName

Comment: Where is the varargs part? There is just no vararg in both your java version and kotlin version.

Answer (score 3):

To remove ambiguity, Kotlin requires 'spread operator' (*) on array which is going to be passed as vararg, i. e.

```
loggingService.logTheMsg("4011", *arrayOf("${expectedVal}", "${actualVal}"))
```

Also, `"${expectedVal}"` should be replaced with `expectedVal`:

```
loggingService.logTheMsg("4011", *arrayOf(expectedVal, actualVal))
```

And, of course, you can use varargs as they intended to be used:

```
loggingService.logTheMsg("4011", expectedVal, actualVal)
```

Comment: And using the same spread operator on the other side , right , that way  i found it working ,also used vararg args:String? in method param , then *args